# Python regex how to remove all zeo from beginning?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have lot of string somethings like this  "01568460144" ,"0005855048560"

I want to remove all zero from beginning. I tried this which only removing one zeo from beginning but I also have others string those have multiple zeo at the beginning.

```
re.sub(r'0','',number)
```

so my expected result will be for **"0005855048560"** this type of string **"5855048560"**

Comment: Why are you bothering with a regex? `mystr.lstrip('0')` does *exactly* what you want (removes any number of `0`s solely from the beginning of the string).

Comment: Okay, if that solves your problem, I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74082952/364696) for it. Give the list of [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) a gander sometime when you get a chance. Between slicing and the various `str` methods, it's pretty rare to need a regex in Python at all; it happens, but where in Perl you're usually doing 90%+ of your string manipulation with a regex, in Python I find it's well under 5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to remove all leading zeroes from a string, skip the regex, and just call `.lstrip('0')` on the string. The `*strip` family of functions are a little weird when the argument isn't a single character, but for the purposes of stripping leading/trailing copies of a single character, they're perfect:

```
>>> s = '000123'
>>> s = s.lstrip('0')
>>> s
'123'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> v = '0001111110'
>>> 
>>> str(int(v))
'1111110'
>>> 
>>> str(int('0005855048560'))
'5855048560'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string should contain only digits, you can use either `isnumeric()` or use re.sub and match only digits:

```
import re

strings = [
    "01568460144",
    "0005855048560",
    "00test",
    "00000",
    "0"
]

for s1 in strings:
    if s1.isnumeric():
        print(f"'{s1.lstrip('0')}'")
    else:
        print(f"'{s1}'")

print("----------------------------")

for s2 in strings:
    res = re.sub(r"^0+(\d*)$", r"\1", s2)
    print(f"'{res}'")
```

Output

```
'1568460144'
'5855048560'
'00test'
''
''
----------------------------
'1568460144'
'5855048560'
'00test'
''
''
```